# Change Record on a Single form In Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that allows the user to select the date at the top. As the user changes the date, it should change the record to reflect. If there is a record for that date already then switch to that record, but if no record for that date create a new one. The table is set to not allow duplicates on the date column. Here is the code I have on the Form_Load event and the respective subs that I call:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Me.cobYear.Value = Year(Date)
    Me.cobMonth.Value = Month(Date)
    DaysChange Me
    Me.cobDate.Value = Day(Date)
    UpdateDate Me
    DoCmd.Maximize

End Sub

Sub DaysChange(objForm As Form)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim DaysInMonth As Integer
    Dim LeapDay As Integer

    LeapDay = 0
    If (Int(objForm.cobYear / 400) = (objForm.cobYear / 400)) Or ((Int(objForm.cobYear / 4) = (objForm.cobYear / 4)) And Not (Int(objForm.cobYear / 100) = (objForm.cobYear / 100))) Then
        LeapDay = IIf(objForm.cobMonth = 2, 1, 0)
    End If

    DaysInMonth = DLookup("DaysInMonth", "tblMonths", "MonthNumber =" & objForm.cobMonth) + LeapDay
    For i = 1 To DaysInMonth
        objForm.cobDate.AddItem Item:=i
    Next i

End Sub

Sub UpdateDate(objForm As Form)

    If Not objForm.cobDate = "" And Not objForm.cobMonth = "" And Not objForm.cobYear = "" Then
        objForm.tbDate.Value = DateSerial(objForm.cobYear, objForm.cobMonth, objForm.cobDate)
        DayOfWeek = Weekday(objForm.tbDate.Value, 2)
        'Me!subfrmDispatchSheet.Form.cobRouteID.Requery
        objForm.lblDayOfWeek.Caption = WeekdayName(Weekday(objForm.tbDate.Value))
        DateOfRecord = objForm.tbDate.Value
    End If

End Sub
```

And this is the code for when a user changes the date:

```
Private Sub cobDate_Change()

    UpdateDate Me
    ChangeRecord

End Sub

Private Sub cobMonth_Change()

    DaysChange Me
    UpdateDate Me
    ChangeRecord

End Sub

Private Sub cobYear_Change()

    DaysChange Me
    UpdateDate Me
    ChangeRecord

End Sub
```

I have tried a few ways to do this.

1) I tried completely in code:

```
Private Sub ChangeRecord()

    If DCount("ShiftDate", "tblShiftRecap", "ShiftDate =" & Me.tbDate.Value) = 0 Then

    Else
        Me.tbShiftID.Value = DLookup("ShiftID", "tblShiftRecap", "ShiftDate =" & Me.tbDate.Value)
    End If
    Me.Requery

End Sub
```

How can I do this on a single form? I know how to do it if I add a subform but not if all the fields are in my single form.

Unfortunately, this tries to add a new record when I load up the form.

2) I tried doing it in the query also

```
SELECT tblShiftRecap.ShiftID, tblShiftRecap.MQFStartTime
FROM tblShiftRecap
WHERE (((tblShiftRecap.ShiftDate)=GetDateOfRecord()));
```

and the functiont that the SQL calls:

```
Public Function GetDateOfRecord()

    GetDateOfRecord = DateOfRecord

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correctly, you want to navigate to a certain record in the current form based on a condition

To navigate the form, the easiest way is to open up a recordset clone, use `.FindFirst`, and then change the current record on the form to the found record:

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone 'Load form records into recordset clone
rs.FindFirst "ShiftDate = " & Format(DateOfRecord, "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#") 'Navigate to date
If Not rs.NoMatch 'If there's a matching record
    Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark 'Navigate to it
End If
```